# -ье/-ие. Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания

Часто замечаю, что некоторые поэты (Пушкин, Лермонтов и т.д.) всячески изменяют окончания слов. Пишут, например, "поколенье", а не "поколение". Вот Лермонтов: "Печально я гляжу на наше поколенье!". 
Это какая-то старая норма или просто сделано, чтобы стихотворный размер не рушить? Так можно писать, если следовать современным правилам русского языка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Тип склонения существительных на -ье и -ие](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/question/tip-skloneniya-sushhestvitelnyih)

Слова «мгновение» и «мгновенье», «прощение» и «прощенье», «склонение» имеют грамматическую категорию среднего рода и окончание -е. Эти существительные среднего рода отнесем ко второму склонению. В разрез с типичным окончанием -е форм предложного падежа существительных среднего рода (в поле, на озере, о море) существительные на -ие имеют окончание -и: *в молчании, о прощении, о склонении*. Существительные на -ье имеют окончание -е: *в молчанье, о прощенье.*

***Слова на -ие являются общеупотребительными, стилистически нейтральными, а существительные на -ье принадлежат разговорной и поэтической речи.***

В **художественной** речи допускается употребление форм предложного падежа существительных среднего рода на -ье с окончанием -и. Например, читаем у А.С. Пушкина: *В молчаньи шел один ты с мыслию великой.*