# Когда форму "в молчаньи" нельзя использовать?

Tags: орфография, окончания

1. В этой теме обычно говорится  **о  стиле:** формы на ***ЬЕ***   являются общеупотребительными и стилистически нейтральными, а формы на ***ЬИ*** используются в художественной, особенно поэтической речи. Приведенные в ПАС примеры относятся **к  XVIII – XIX веку**, а более современные **стилизованы** под высокий стиль или старину.
2. А есть разница между двумя вариантами по **грамматике и смыслу**? Можно ли привести примеры из современной речи, где окончание на ***ЬИ*** использовать нежелательно с этой точки зрения?

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**[ПАС](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp71.php)** **§ 71. Падежные формы существительных на -ий, -ие, -ия.**

Примечание. **В художественной**, особенно поэтической, речи **допускается** написание форм предл. п. существительных сред, рода на -**ье** (обычно при предлоге **в**) с окончанием -и, напр.: **В молчаньи** шел один ты с мыслию великой (П.);

**Ответы справочной службы**, вопрос №210563. Здравствуйте! Как будет правильно: Ты сидишь предо мною в молчаньЕ или в молчаньИ? ОТВЕТ. Корректно: ***в молчанье.***

**Темы на форуме** [1](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460139/%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/460141#460141) и [2](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461955/%D0%92-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5-%D0%98%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B8/461968#461968)